# How to add an item from a list to another list

Tags: c#, list

I have a list called "enctypechances" and I want to give the item "Land" to another list.

```
public static List<Encounter> enctypechances = new List<Encounter>();
Encounter Land = new Encounter(20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 5, 5, 4, 4, 1, 1);
```

Here is where I want to add the "Land" item

```
List<Encounter> enctypes = new List<Encounter>();

void Start () {
    enctypes.Add( ??? );
}
```

Comment: What would be wrong with `enctypes.Add( Land )`?

Comment: @Icepickle It says it's not available in the current context.

Comment: Then I guess you need to change `Land`'s scope. You haven't shown us enough code to know what the scope is, but you can easily tell that it's wrong from the error message.

Comment: I gave Land `public static` and called from the another class `enctypes.Add(Land);`. No need for enctypeschanes anymore. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

`Land` has to be visible within the `start()` scope. You have to declare it inside the method, pass it in as an argument to the method, or make sure it's otherwise visible inside the class.

As others have commented though, you should probably show us more code for a more specific answer.

Comment: I gave Land `public static` and called from the another class `enctypes.Add(Land);`. No need for enctypeschanes anymore. Thank you for help.